# $\eta$-reduction not locally confluent on well-typed terms

Tags: type-theory, lambda-calculus

[This paper](https://www.cse.chalmers.se/%7Eabela/lfsigma.pdf) says: "In the presence of a unit type, $\eta$-reduction is not even locally confluent on well-typed terms [20]."

[20] is a reference to a 300-page book with no further details and I cannot find the relevant example there. So can you give an example of $\eta$-reduction not being locally confluent on well-typed terms?

Comment: Where did you find the book? I didn't find an online version.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, $\eta$ *reduction* for unit is terribly behaved. Suppose you are in a context $\Gamma \triangleq x:1, y:1$.

Then, the unit term $\Gamma \vdash \left\langle\right\rangle : 1$ has the following eta-reductions:

$$
\begin{array}{lcl}
\left\langle\right\rangle & \leadsto_\eta & x \\
\left\langle\right\rangle & \leadsto_\eta & y \\
\end{array}
$$

There are no further $\beta$ or $\eta$ reductions, so local confluence fails.

In practice (and in theory, actually), what you want to do instead is $\eta$-**expansion**. You have to do it in a typed way, but it is fantastically well-behaved.

Comment: Or stop using $\eta$-rules and use an extensionality rule instead.

Comment: What do you mean by an extensionality rule?

Comment: See [Definition 3.22](https://arxiv.org/abs/2103.07397), for the unit type it is $$\frac{\vdash a : 1 \qquad \vdash b : 1}{\vdash a \equiv_1 b}$$ and examples are on the next page.